# a select item that commends another select item

Tags: php, javascript

I have two select items: "agence" and "code". I'd like to make the selected option in the "code" select item to be changed whenever we change the selected index in "agence" select item in a way to show the right "code" for the right "agence" in the select items. Here's what I've done so far but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<?php
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bp', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
?>

<script>
var agence = document.getElementById('agence');
var code = document.getElementById('code');

agence.addEventListener('change', function() {
code.selectedIndex = agence.selectedIndex;
}, false);
</script>


<label for="agence">Agence</label><select name="agence" id="agence"><?php $age = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM agences ;') or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo())); ?><?php while($ddonnees2 = $age->fetch()){?><option value="<?php echo $ddonnees2['Agence'];?>"><?php echo $ddonnees2['Agence'];?></option><?php } ?></select>
<label for="code">code</label><select name="code" id="code"><?php $age = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM agences ;') or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo())); ?><?php while($ddonnees2 = $age->fetch()){?><option value="<?php echo $ddonnees2['Code'];?>"><?php echo $ddonnees2['Code'];?></option><?php } ?></select>
```

Comment: Why do you have to use two dropdown lists? Can't you just use one, with choices such as `<option value="<?php echo $ddonnees2['Code'];?>"><?php echo $ddonnees2['Agence'];?></option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use ajax and jquery. Create a php file then send id of agence which selected in select and send it to the php file with ajax. Then echo the result with for or foreach statement to produce options. After that, retrieve the data in a jquery and success function of ajax then change the html of the code select.

Comment: You should alweays try to elaborate your idea with a code sample to help others better understand what you are explaining. Though i get what you are explaining, it would definitely be more helpful with a code sample. PLease consider adding one to your response

Comment: You know I'm new to stackoverflow's answering system. and i don't know how to add code in highlighter form. If you help me about this I will thank you.

Comment: With pleasure : You can use the {}  on top of the response or question textbox which will add "enter code here" to your response, just replace this text with your code and it will show in the preview as formatted code.